# Javafx WebView OpenLayers Map OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: webview, javafx-2, openlayers

I am adding Openlayers map to WebView added to a swing panel.
Heap memory usage increases steeply while zooming/adding layer/replacing layer.
Ultimately results in `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`
I had maximum memory set to 500MB.
Tried in both JDK 1.7.0_40 & 1.8.0.

I think Images added/replaced through javascript  are not getting removed from memory properly.
Profiling shows Heapdatabuffer retains instances of ImageFrame

eg:

```
- value: com.sun.javafx.iio.ImageFrame[] #3 (1 items)  
 -> [0] - class: com.sun.javafx.iio.ImageFrame[], value: com.sun.javafx.iio.ImageFrame #3
```

Is there any way to remove the image instances from memory? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sunish reported this a bug [RT-33238](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-33238) (which was accepted and is currently open).

Comment: Implemented required functionality using DJ (http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/) + Xulrunner. 
Memory usage for my application is not crossing 40MB.
It was shooting up to more than 1GB with WebView.
Thanks for DJ